# how to print titles and subtitles after click with angular?

Tags: angular, title, sublist

I did menus and submenus with angular, [cf here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnkg3h-xppmzz?file=app%2Flist-overview-example.html) but now I would like to print these titles in another mat-card part (after click on them) like this:
if I click on 1.1 menu :

> - 1
> - 1.1
> - some text

... if I click on 2 menu :

> - 2
> - some other text.

I tried with

```
(click)="selectedStep = step;selectedsubStep = substep"
```

or

```
ng-model="substep"
```

into *ngFor loop but without succes, how to do, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you looking for [this](https://material.angular.io/components/tree)??

Comment: I saw this before, it was a possibility but I preferred my solution...if I can go to the end :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can change h4 to div other header level

```
<mat-list >
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
      <mat-list-item  *ngFor="let subItem of item.subItems">
        {{ subItem.name }}
      </mat-list-item>  
  </ng-container>
</mat-list>
```

Comment: thanks, there's an idea but it's not what I want : with this, titles are written after titles in the menu part. I would like print titles and subtitles in another mat-card part after click on menu

Comment: oooh i see what you mean